# Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing with Random Forest

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, training-data, roc

I've been trying to train a model with Random Forest but it shows me this error:

```
> rf <- train(x = Fraud_trainX, 
+             y = Fraud_trainY,
+             method = "rf",
+             ntree = 500,
+             tuneGrid = rfGrid,
+             metric = "ROC",
+             trControl = ctrl,
+             importance = TRUE)
Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing:
      ROC           Sens          Spec    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :3     NA's   :3     NA's   :3
```

**Here is the summary of the database:**

```
  summary(Fraud_trainX)
 WeekOfMonthClaimed      Age       RepNumber        Deductible     DriverRating  
 Min.   :1.000      Min.   :16   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :300.0   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:2.000      1st Qu.:31   1st Qu.: 4.000   1st Qu.:400.0   1st Qu.:1.000  
 Median :3.000      Median :39   Median : 8.000   Median :400.0   Median :3.000  
 Mean   :2.706      Mean   :41   Mean   : 8.434   Mean   :408.2   Mean   :2.495  
 3rd Qu.:4.000      3rd Qu.:49   3rd Qu.:12.000   3rd Qu.:400.0   3rd Qu.:3.000  
 Max.   :5.000      Max.   :80   Max.   :16.000   Max.   :700.0   Max.   :4.000  
      Year        ClaimSize          Month         WeekOfMonth      DayOfWeek    
 Min.   :1994   Min.   :     0   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:1994   1st Qu.:  4156   1st Qu.: 3.000   1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:2.000  
 Median :1995   Median :  8059   Median : 6.000   Median :3.000   Median :4.000  
 Mean   :1995   Mean   : 22437   Mean   : 6.462   Mean   :2.789   Mean   :3.812  
 3rd Qu.:1996   3rd Qu.: 38028   3rd Qu.:10.000   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:5.000  
 Max.   :1996   Max.   :141394   Max.   :12.000   Max.   :5.000   Max.   :7.000  
 DayOfWeekClaimed  MonthClaimed         Sex         MaritalStatus  
 Min.   :1.000    Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:2.000    1st Qu.: 3.000   1st Qu.:1.0000   1st Qu.:1.000  
 Median :3.000    Median : 6.000   Median :1.0000   Median :2.000  
 Mean   :2.828    Mean   : 6.445   Mean   :0.8414   Mean   :1.719  
 3rd Qu.:4.000    3rd Qu.:10.000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:2.000  
 Max.   :7.000    Max.   :12.000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :3.000  
     Fault         VehiclePrice   Days_Policy_Accident Days_Policy_Claim
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.000        Min.   :1.000    
 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:4.000        1st Qu.:3.000    
 Median :0.0000   Median :2.000   Median :4.000        Median :3.000    
 Mean   :0.2744   Mean   :2.727   Mean   :3.977        Mean   :2.994    
 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:4.000        3rd Qu.:3.000    
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :6.000   Max.   :4.000        Max.   :3.000    
 PastNumberOfClaims  AgeOfVehicle   AgeOfPolicyHolder PoliceReportFiled
 Min.   :0.000      Min.   :0.000   Min.   :2.000     Min.   :0.00000  
 1st Qu.:0.000      1st Qu.:6.000   1st Qu.:5.000     1st Qu.:0.00000  
 Median :1.000      Median :7.000   Median :6.000     Median :0.00000  
 Mean   :1.364      Mean   :6.748   Mean   :6.028     Mean   :0.02846  
 3rd Qu.:2.000      3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:7.000     3rd Qu.:0.00000  
 Max.   :3.000      Max.   :8.000   Max.   :9.000     Max.   :1.00000  
 WitnessPresent       AgentType       NumberOfSuppliments AddressChange_Claim
 Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.000       Min.   :0.0000     
 1st Qu.:0.000000   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.000       1st Qu.:0.0000     
 Median :0.000000   Median :0.00000   Median :1.000       Median :0.0000     
 Mean   :0.005126   Mean   :0.01467   Mean   :1.197       Mean   :0.1801     
 3rd Qu.:0.000000   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:3.000       3rd Qu.:0.0000     
 Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :3.000       Max.   :3.0000     
  NumberOfCars     Make_Accura         Make_BMW         Make_Chevrolet  
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.0000000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.0000000   1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :0.0000   Median :0.00000   Median :0.0000000   Median :0.0000  
 Mean   :0.1027   Mean   :0.03465   Mean   :0.0008839   Mean   :0.1114  
 3rd Qu.:0.0000   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.0000000   3rd Qu.:0.0000  
 Max.   :3.0000   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.0000000   Max.   :1.0000  
   Make_Dodge        Make_Ferrari   Make_Ford         Make_Honda    
 Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0     Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.000000   1st Qu.:0     1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :0.000000   Median :0     Median :0.00000   Median :0.0000  
 Mean   :0.007248   Mean   :0     Mean   :0.03005   Mean   :0.1745  
 3rd Qu.:0.000000   3rd Qu.:0     3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.0000  
 Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :0     Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.0000  
  Make_Jaguar          Make_Lexus          Make_Mazda      Make_Mecedes      
 Min.   :0.0000000   Min.   :0.0000000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000000  
 1st Qu.:0.0000000   1st Qu.:0.0000000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000000  
 Median :0.0000000   Median :0.0000000   Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000000  
 Mean   :0.0007071   Mean   :0.0001768   Mean   :0.1416   Mean   :0.0001768  
 3rd Qu.:0.0000000   3rd Qu.:0.0000000   3rd Qu.:0.0000   3rd Qu.:0.0000000  
 Max.   :1.0000000   Max.   :1.0000000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000000  
  Make_Mercury       Make_Nisson        Make_Pontiac     Make_Porche
 Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0   
 1st Qu.:0.000000   1st Qu.:0.000000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0   
 Median :0.000000   Median :0.000000   Median :0.0000   Median :0   
 Mean   :0.005126   Mean   :0.001768   Mean   :0.2523   Mean   :0   
 3rd Qu.:0.000000   3rd Qu.:0.000000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0   
 Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :0   
   Make_Saab         Make_Saturn        Make_Toyota      Make_VW       
 Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0.00   Min.   :0.00000  
 1st Qu.:0.000000   1st Qu.:0.000000   1st Qu.:0.00   1st Qu.:0.00000  
 Median :0.000000   Median :0.000000   Median :0.00   Median :0.00000  
 Mean   :0.005834   Mean   :0.002828   Mean   :0.21   Mean   :0.02086  
 3rd Qu.:0.000000   3rd Qu.:0.000000   3rd Qu.:0.00   3rd Qu.:0.00000  
 Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :1.00   Max.   :1.00000  
 BasePolicy_All Perils BasePolicy_Collision BasePolicy_Liability
 Min.   :0.0000        Min.   :0.0000       Min.   :0.0000      
 1st Qu.:0.0000        1st Qu.:0.0000       1st Qu.:0.0000      
 Median :0.0000        Median :0.0000       Median :0.0000      
 Mean   :0.2873        Mean   :0.3882       Mean   :0.3246      
 3rd Qu.:1.0000        3rd Qu.:1.0000       3rd Qu.:1.0000      
 Max.   :1.0000        Max.   :1.0000       Max.   :1.0000      
 AccidentArea_Rural AccidentArea_Urban PolicyType_SedA  PolicyType_SedC
 Min.   :0.0000     Min.   :0.0000     Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.000  
 1st Qu.:0.0000     1st Qu.:1.0000     1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.000  
 Median :0.0000     Median :1.0000     Median :0.0000   Median :0.000  
 Mean   :0.1018     Mean   :0.8982     Mean   :0.2648   Mean   :0.364  
 3rd Qu.:0.0000     3rd Qu.:1.0000     3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.000  
 Max.   :1.0000     Max.   :1.0000     Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.000  
 PolicyType_SedL  PolicyType_SpoAL    PolicyType_SpoC   PolicyType_UtiA  
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000000   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.00000  
 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000000   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.00000  
 Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000000   Median :0.00000   Median :0.00000  
 Mean   :0.3231   Mean   :0.0007071   Mean   :0.02227   Mean   :0.02192  
 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0.0000000   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.00000  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000000   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.00000  
 PolicyType_UtiCL   VehicleCategory_Sedan VehicleCategory_Sport
 Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0.0000        Min.   :0.0000       
 1st Qu.:0.000000   1st Qu.:0.0000        1st Qu.:0.0000       
 Median :0.000000   Median :1.0000        Median :0.0000       
 Mean   :0.003182   Mean   :0.6288        Mean   :0.3461       
 3rd Qu.:0.000000   3rd Qu.:1.0000        3rd Qu.:1.0000       
 Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :1.0000        Max.   :1.0000       
 VehicleCategory_Utility
 Min.   :0.0000         
 1st Qu.:0.0000         
 Median :0.0000         
 Mean   :0.0251         
 3rd Qu.:0.0000         
 Max.   :1.0000
```

**Here the structure of the database:**

```
str(Fraud_trainX)
'data.frame':   5657 obs. of  61 variables:
 $ WeekOfMonthClaimed     : num  1 4 3 5 3 5 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ Age                    : num  21 34 71 52 28 38 41 28 47 60 ...
 $ RepNumber              : num  12 15 7 13 11 16 15 6 13 16 ...
 $ Deductible             : num  300 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 ...
 $ DriverRating           : num  1 4 3 1 1 1 4 1 2 4 ...
 $ Year                   : num  1994 1994 1994 1994 1994 ...
 $ ClaimSize              : num  55526 59294 62624 103421 59748 ...
 $ Month                  : int  12 1 3 3 1 8 4 7 1 3 ...
 $ WeekOfMonth            : int  5 3 2 5 3 4 4 5 2 3 ...
 $ DayOfWeek              : int  3 3 7 1 5 2 4 7 6 1 ...
 $ DayOfWeekClaimed       : int  2 1 3 1 5 1 3 3 1 2 ...
 $ MonthClaimed           : int  1 1 3 3 1 8 5 8 1 4 ...
 $ Sex                    : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ MaritalStatus          : int  1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Fault                  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ VehiclePrice           : int  6 6 6 2 6 6 6 2 2 2 ...
 $ Days_Policy_Accident   : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Days_Policy_Claim      : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ PastNumberOfClaims     : int  0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 3 ...
 $ AgeOfVehicle           : int  3 6 8 8 7 6 7 7 8 8 ...
 $ AgeOfPolicyHolder      : int  4 5 9 7 5 6 6 5 7 8 ...
 $ PoliceReportFiled      : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WitnessPresent         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AgentType              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NumberOfSuppliments    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ AddressChange_Claim    : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 ...
 $ NumberOfCars           : int  2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Make_Accura            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_BMW               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Chevrolet         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Make_Dodge             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Ferrari           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Ford              : int  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Honda             : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Jaguar            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Lexus             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Mazda             : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Mecedes           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Mercury           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Nisson            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Pontiac           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ Make_Porche            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Saab              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Saturn            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_Toyota            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Make_VW                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BasePolicy_All Perils  : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ BasePolicy_Collision   : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ BasePolicy_Liability   : int  1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ AccidentArea_Rural     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AccidentArea_Urban     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PolicyType_SedA        : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ PolicyType_SedC        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ PolicyType_SedL        : int  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ PolicyType_SpoAL       : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PolicyType_SpoC        : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PolicyType_UtiA        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PolicyType_UtiCL       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ VehicleCategory_Sedan  : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ VehicleCategory_Sport  : int  1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ VehicleCategory_Utility: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

**Here is the summary of the response variable:**

```
summary(Fraud_trainY)
 No   Yes 
5220  310 

str(Fraud_trainY)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Si": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

**And here is the control I use for the model:**

```
indx <- createMultiFolds(Fraud_trainY, k = 5, times = 2)
str(indx)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",index = indx, 
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     sampling = "up",
                     classProbs = TRUE)
```

**Finally, I put again the parameters that I use for the model:**

```
sqtmtry<- round(sqrt(ncol(Fraud_trainX) - 1))
rfGrid <- expand.grid(mtry = c(round(sqtmtry / 2), sqtmtry, 2 * sqtmtry))

rf <- train(x = Fraud_trainX, 
            y = Fraud_trainY,
            method = "rf",
            ntree = 500,
            tuneGrid = rfGrid,
            metric = "ROC",
            trControl = ctrl,
            importance = TRUE)
```

I have already tried to load the pROC library before the model and it has not been successful. I have already eliminated the rows that contained NA from all the variables, the response variable already has the levels "No" and "Yes". I have also done this training for C5.0 ("`C5.0`"), Neural Networks ("`nnet`"), SVM ("`svmRadial`") and Logistic Regression ("`multinom`") and in all of them I have used the ROC curve as metric, in all of them the data have served me and it gives me the result of the model, this is the only model that marks me some kind of error.

**Here a dput() of the database:**

```
dput(Fraud_trainX[1:50, c(1:33, 47:61)])
structure(list(WeekOfMonthClaimed = c(1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 
4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1
), Age = c(21, 34, 71, 52, 28, 38, 41, 28, 47, 60, 39, 42, 35, 
72, 29, 32, 59, 45, 30, 37, 49, 26, 40, 64, 55, 44, 27, 28, 60, 
33, 27, 29, 33, 37, 44, 39, 74, 25, 41, 37, 31, 47, 50, 51, 29, 
18, 60, 41, 29, 42), RepNumber = c(12, 15, 7, 13, 11, 16, 15, 
6, 13, 16, 12, 2, 11, 16, 8, 9, 9, 8, 5, 11, 6, 13, 16, 5, 12, 
16, 9, 5, 12, 9, 1, 16, 10, 6, 9, 1, 13, 2, 12, 14, 12, 1, 2, 
1, 14, 14, 6, 9, 9, 2), Deductible = c(300, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 500, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400), DriverRating = c(1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 
1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 2), Year = c(1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994), 
    ClaimSize = c(55526.0694212824, 59294.4555709387, 62624.2287152393, 
    103420.785274585, 59747.5494391561, 54340.8120323971, 52273.7919473849, 
    6659.00666681981, 1298.64391192781, 22262.9336731903, 6856.39679898433, 
    23868.7894652824, 2714.29004930399, 9157.70733868184, 9947.15647459238, 
    4658.42724707721, 16456.6310582078, 58488.9243920724, 100701.440976097, 
    74810.309390384, 6238.90822766288, 2876.11265102375, 50099.5570573993, 
    2922.35731892594, 8960.04326512298, 7292.54144233941, 3188.997856986, 
    8027.19227730757, 63535.6100346822, 12593.4143671265, 2709.0088113366, 
    56479.0906568321, 84417.6742873722, 8861.97370679354, 2335.44650783732, 
    5015.33016030941, 5790.73446465997, 55591.493622206, 2103.18508925209, 
    53404.0297019986, 5464.35640351837, 5054.19523630365, 5514.0821718031, 
    14029.0334523622, 767.664492706068, 8606.04253787013, 9195.6689726381, 
    4191.31694249056, 6061.06981961005, 13980.7120145997), Month = c(12L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 
    10L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 11L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 12L, 
    4L, 11L, 4L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 12L), WeekOfMonth = c(5L, 3L, 2L, 
    5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L), DayOfWeek = c(3L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
    5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L), DayOfWeekClaimed = c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), MonthClaimed = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 
    5L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    5L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 11L, 4L, 10L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L), Sex = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MaritalStatus = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Fault = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), VehiclePrice = c(6L, 
    6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Days_Policy_Accident = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L), Days_Policy_Claim = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), PastNumberOfClaims = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 3L), AgeOfVehicle = c(3L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
    7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 
    7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L), 
    AgeOfPolicyHolder = c(4L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 
    8L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
    7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 
    6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L), PoliceReportFiled = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), WitnessPresent = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    AgentType = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NumberOfSuppliments = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 0L), AddressChange_Claim = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), NumberOfCars = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Make_Accura = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Make_BMW = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Make_Chevrolet = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Make_Dodge = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Make_Ferrari = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Make_Ford = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `BasePolicy_All Perils` = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), BasePolicy_Collision = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L), BasePolicy_Liability = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AccidentArea_Rural = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AccidentArea_Urban = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), PolicyType_SedA = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), PolicyType_SedC = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), PolicyType_SedL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), PolicyType_SpoAL = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PolicyType_SpoC = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PolicyType_UtiA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), PolicyType_UtiCL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), VehicleCategory_Sedan = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), VehicleCategory_Sport = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), VehicleCategory_Utility = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 26L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 34L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 44L, 46L, 49L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 72L, 74L, 
76L, 78L, 82L, 87L, 91L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L), class = "data.frame")
```

The columns that I omit are more car brands, so I thought it was enough to put some, also that with all the variables the R console would not let me see all the lines.

**And from the response variable:**

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Si"), class = "factor")
```

**My libraries:**

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(DMwR)
library(C50)
library(kernlab)
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
library(lattice)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(gridExtra)
library(pROC)
library(ROCR)
library(nnet)
library(tidyverse)
```

Comment: i had to do this `Fraud_trainY[1:20] <- 'Si'` but your example runs fine for me. you can try `debugonce(caret:::train.default)` with your full data and step through the [train source code](https://github.com/cran/caret/blob/master/R/train.default.R#L682) to see what's going on

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but how do I do that specifically if possible. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: type `debugonce(caret:::train.default)` then run your `train(...)` command which will run `train` line-by-line when you hit enter. you can examine all the objects within the function during debug as if they are in your console. type `Q` to exit debug

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times... [Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing in Random Forest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66113466/something-is-wrong-all-the-roc-metric-values-are-missing-in-random-forest)

Comment: if your question is closed, you don't post the same question again just to get around it, the best action would be to edit it

Comment: The response variable you provided doesn't work. I used  ```Fraud_trainY = factor(sample(c("No","Si"),size=50,replace=TRUE))``` and it runs fine